# Redshift COPY command with "^A" delimiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, delimiter, emr

I am trying to use a control A ("^A") delimited file to load into redshift using COPY command, I see default delimiter is pipe (|) and with CSV it is comma.

I couldnt file a way to use `^A`, when i tried COPY command with `^A` or `\x01`, it is throwing below message. Anybody tried this before? documentation says we can use delimiter, but no clue on using `^A`.

> Password:
>   ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used `'\\001'` as a delimiter for ctrl+A based field separation in redshift and also in Pig.

Example :

```
copy redshiftinfo from 's3://mybucket/data/redshiftinfo.txt' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>' 
delimiter '\\001'
```

Comment: Good find! See reference to `octal` on [COPY Delimiter documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-delimiter).

Comment: @cloudninja please mark this as an answer, if you think this answered your question well. I can add additional details if you suggest so. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the COPY command with \\001 delimiter and it worked well. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: If a file will be tab delimited, then how to handle? Can anyone please suggest.